# Setup ios in configure application framework in dreamweaver 5.5

Tags: ios, dreamweaver

I am not able to setup ios in dreamweaver 5.5. This is showing only android SDK Path. I want to configure ios also on dreamweaver. I am using 11.5 Build 5366 Adobe dreamweaver.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver debugging for iOS is only available on OS X.

Stated in the [Packaging web applications as native mobile applications (CS5.5)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSeffff8bffc80208478c8d43312e240fe0ad-8000.html)

> **Windows - iOS**
>
> iOS is only available for users with an Apple computer